# What happend on my Lenovo G770 while starting if the Display is black for about one minute

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, lenovo-laptop

There is a Lenovo G770 with Windows 7 installed, every time I start the Notebook I get a black screen for about one minute after the Windows start Video is shown. I change the Grafiktyp in BIOS from switchable Adapter to UMA graphic, I installed new Driver for Display, Chipset and VGA but nothing happend. After reinstall Windows all works fine with the original driver, but after Install all Update of Windows the Problem occurs.

Anybody know what happend in this time? I send the Notebook to lenovo and get it back with a fresh install ... if I install the updates the problem occurs.

Comment: If the updates include one for the graphics driver, don't allow it to be installed.

Comment: I installed the base Driver they was delivered, too. Also the newest one and the base graphics driver from intel.